# Which one is the external system actors?

Tags: uml, actor, use-case, use-case-diagram, system-integration

I have Use case like this.
[image]

This is an Emergency Monitoring Use Case and actors, which one is the external system actors?
I just learn Use Case Diagram, and I think the answer is Monitoring Operator, But I confused with the another actor, especially Monitoring sensor and Remote System? Is Another actor an external system actor too? But the option just :
a. Remote System
b. Monitoring Operator
c. Monitoring Sensor
d. Generate Alarm
Can you give a link, so I can read it, too prove my answer is true / wrong.

Answer (score 3):

An [actor](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor.html) is always external to the system. An external system actor is a non-human actor.

In your diagram, the `Monitoring operator` seems to be a security agent looking at the screen and reacting to what's happening.

The `Remote service` seems to be a non-human actor that interact with some use case, probably to automatically feed data into the system:

- The diagram has a syntactic error:  the arrow from `Remote System` and `Monitoring sensor` to `Remote service`  needs to be a [generalization](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html) arrow (normally a big white triangle.  A use case does not allow to associate actors between them).  This means that both are special forms of `Remote service`.
- All these three remote actors are therefore candidate for an external system:

  - However, `Remote service` seems meant here more as a placeholder for its specializations. You could therefore as well omit it.
  - If the sensor interacts with a system as an actor, it should be complex enough to be autonomous.  This means that it's not a passive sensor but could be conisdered as a small active system. I would name it as well.
  - And of course, the `Remote system` is without a doubt an external system actor.